# Selecting XML Nodes with Multiple Xpaths in OneTime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find values under one node in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800833/find-values-under-one-node-in-xml)

**Sample XML File:**

```
<Book>
<Page id="1">
<Head>Preface</Head>
<Body>
<Paragraph>
    <Line>
        <Word>
            <Char>T</Char>
            <Char>h</Char>
            <Char>i</Char>
            <Char>s</Char>
        </Word>
        <Word>is sample xml file.</Word>
    </Line>
</Paragraph>
</Body>
</Page>
```

**Note:** Here, sample text to search is 'I'.
For Selection Word without having  nodes , xPath expression is:

```
string Word_Char_XPath="//CHAR[contains(translate(text(),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),'I')]/..";
```

For selection of words having only  nodes, xPath expression is:

```
string Word_XPath="//WORD[contains(translate(text(), abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ), 'I')]";
```

Code for selection of words containing "i"

```
XmlDocument objXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList objXmlNodeList;
objXmlDoc.Load(sFilePath);
objXmlNodeList = objXmlDoc.SelectNodes(Word_Char_XPath+" or "+ Word_XPath);
```

**Problem:** 
By 'or' two xpath expression it returns either true or false, but if all word nodes to be selected on matching criteria (both xpaths)then how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved it by getting some help form Net.
Where I's using '**or**' operator, use '**|**' (**Pipe Sign**) operator to combine the values of two XPath  Expression. It will select all the nodes in xml file which match either condition in XPath expression.
Happy Programming !